# Use socket.io across diffrent routes in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have different routes in my `node js` application and now i want to use `socket.io` in **every route** to make my `node` and `react js` application realtime. But, i have the below structure of my **node js** application.

**router.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const worksheetController = require('../controllers/worksheet');
const attendenceController = require('../controllers/attendence');

router.route('/worksheets')
 .get(
    worksheetController.getWorksheet
 )
 .post(
    worksheetController.validateWorksheet,
    worksheetController.addWorksheet,
    attendenceController.markAttendence
 );

router.route('/attendances')
 .get(
    attendenceController.getAttendance
 );

module.exports = router;
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = require('./router');

const app = express();
app.use('/api', router);

app.listen('5000', () => {
  console.log('Listening on port');
});

module.exports = app;
```

How can I use socket.io for different routes?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to correlate express routes and socket.io events. They are two different things. Perhaps you can add the related logic in the controllers and call the functions from socket.io events as you have done with express routes.

eg:

```
const worksheetController = require('../controllers/worksheet');

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('my event', function (data) {
    const myData = worksheetController.getDataForOtherEvent(data);
    console.log(myData);
  });
});
```